# Let a, b, an m be integers. If a and b are relatively prime and a|m and b|m, then ab|m.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove and extend of disprove and salvage this statement.

I posted a similar post a few minutes ago.  I've been stuck on these two problems for a while and I have no idea what to do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Write 1 as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ with integer coefficients. That's usually a good first step.

Comment: I hope you have deleted the similar post. You should start by working out some examples, to decide whether to prove or disprove the statement. Please show some of your work and  we may be able to help.

Comment: Other duplicates: [If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a$ and $b$ divide $c$, then so does $ab$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407540/if-gcda-b-1-and-a-and-b-divide-c-then-so-does-ab), and [If $a \mid c, b \mid c, \gcd (a,b)=1$ then $ab \mid c.$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408435/if-a-mid-c-b-mid-c-gcd-a-b-1-then-ab-mid-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [Showing that if $(a,b)=1$ and if $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ then $ab \mid c$, in GCD domains](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472618/showing-that-if-a-b-1-and-if-a-mid-c-and-b-mid-c-then-ab-mid-c-in-gc?noredirect=1&lq=1), and many others

Comment: Use bézout identity (as you your previous post): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard. If $(a,b)=1$ then $\exists r,s\in Z$ st $ar+bs=1$, so $m=mar+mbs$. Because $a|m$ and $b|m$ then the right side of the equation is divisible by $ab$. Done